# Read protection key rights with inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I know that protections for each key are defined with a per-CPU user-accessible register (PKRU). Each of these is a 32-bit register storing two bits (Access Disable and Write Disable) for each of 16 keys (taken from kernel.org), and that the `pkru` register can be read with the x86 `rdpkru` instruction.

I want to call `rdpkru` with inline assembly and when I do so, it always results in a seg fault. The documentation says that `rdpkru` -  *Reads the value of PKRU into EAX and clears EDX. ECX must be 0 when RDPKRU is executed; otherwise, a general-protection exception (#GP) occurs.*

```c
static uint32_t pkru;

static inline void read__rdpkru_u32(void)
{
    asm volatile("movl $0, %%ecx; rdpkru" : "=a"(pkru) : : "ecx");
}
```

```c
int main(void)
{
    pkey = pkey_alloc(0, 0);
    read__rdpkru_u32();
    ...
}
```

**Why do I get a seg fault?**

Comment: You forgot to clobber edx, for one thing.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping this in the debugger?  What instruction triggers the fault?  You might also zero ecx with `xor %%ecx, %%ecx`.  It's a bit shorter.